# Labeling curves in r, plotting object is not a data.frame

Tags: r

Currently, I'm working in SimInf package. I want to label result plot curves on the graph or right-hand side of the graph next to the curves. Usual labeling techniques did not work here, because here the plot object is not a data.frame.
This is the usual code that can produce the regular plot. I want to label these curves on the graph or right-hand side of the graph.

````
library(SimInf)
transitions <- c("S -> beta*S*I/(S+E+I+R+D) -> E ", "E->epsi*E->I" , "I -> gamma*I -> R",
                 "I -> mu*I -> D")
compartments <- c("S", "E", "I", "R","D")
u0 <- data.frame(S = 9989,  E= 10, I = 1, R = 0, D=0)
model1 <- mparse(transitions = transitions, compartments = compartments,
                 gdata = c(beta = 0.16, epsi=0.25, gamma = 0.077,  mu=0.01), u0 = u0, tspan = 1:250)
set.seed(3)
set_num_threads(1)
result<- run(model = model1)
run(result)
plot(result)```
````